# What NBA players have won both Defensive Player of the Year and Most Valuable Player?

Tags: trivia, nba, awards

Which NBA players have won both the awards of Defensive Player of the Year (DPOY) and Most Valuable Player?

Have any players won both awards in different seasons across their career? Have any players won both awards in the same season?

If any players have done so, in which season and with which team did these players earn the awards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Won MVP and DPOY during the same season:**

- Michael Jordan, Chicago Bulls, [1988](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1988.html).
- Hakeem Olajuwon, Houston Rockets, [1994](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1994.html).

[Source](https://www.sun-sentinel.com/sports/fl-xpm-2013-04-24-sfl-miami-heat-lebron-james-s042413-story.html)

> With James expected to again be named NBA Most Valuable Player, it means he will have come up just short in joining Michael Jordan (1988) and Hakeem Olajuwon (1994) as the only players to be named MVP and Defensive Player of the Year for the same season.

**Won MVP and DPOY during the course of their careers:**

- David Robinson, San Antonio Spurs, [1992 DPOY](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1992.html), [1995 MVP](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1995.html)
- Kevin Garnett, Minnesota Timberwolves/Boston Celtics, [2004 MVP (Timberwolves)](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2004.html), [2008 DPOY (Celtics)](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2008.html)

Answer (score -2):

Giannis antetokoumpo has won both awards in the same year in 2020

[Source](https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2020.html)

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Please add a source to your answer